# Nuxt Generate Dynamic Routes Path

Tags: vue.js, wp-api

I'm creating a site with wp-api. All my pages are inside:

`- pages
-- _slug`

If my page slug are site.com/about

`- pages
-- about`

Nuxt will generate html like this. But... If my path are site.com/company/about

Can I create this routes?

PS: I'm using wordpress api for that. So if my pages has parent pages, the path are: site.com/parent/child

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `routes` key in `nuxt.config.js` to do this.

The docs are here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#routes

In a nutshell, you can write a function in `nuxt.config.js`:`generate.routes` which generates the pages for you.

Here is an example: `nuxt.config.js`:

```
const axios = require('axios')

module.exports = {
  ...
  generate: {
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get('https://your-wordpress-api/')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data.map((page) => {
          let route = '/whatever/you/like/' + page.slug
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Some tips:

- You can add the payload to speed things up a little: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-code-payload-code-
- If you need to make a number of requests, use `axios.spread`